# SoundCloud API streaming bug

Tags: api, streaming, soundcloud

I'm using the SoundCloud API to stream songs but am experiencing the following (what I think is a) bug.

When clicking a button the track is streamed and played, when I click another, the playback gets paused. This is basically done with this piece of code:

```
var playerVar;
SC.initialize({ client_id: 'sorryCantPublishThat' });

$('#play').click(function(){
  SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackID ).then(function(player){
    player.play();
    playerVar = player;
  });
});

$('#pause').click(function(){
  playerVar.pause();
});
```

This works fine, as long as i don't click play again, after pausing the stream. Because then it plays, but I cannot stop the stream. I have to click the play button once again, then I can stop it.

Any ideas if I'm doing something wrong or if it's a bug? Any besides that, how can I get this working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out how to get this working.
I now stream all the tracks as soon as the page gets loaded, and not only when the play button is clicked. Every track has it's own variable:

```
SC.initialize({ client_id: '' });

SC.stream('/tracks/' + track.id ).then(function(player){

    player.on('time', function () {
        // update 
    });

    soundCloudPlayers[ track.id ] = player;

});
```

And then, when the play button is clicked:

```
$('.play').click(function() {

    var player = soundCloudPlayers[ $(this).attr('data-trackid') ];
    player.play();

    player.on('time', function () {
        // update the current playback position indicator
    });
});
```

So this is also the place where the event listeners are placed.